# How to modify HTACCESS file for non-WordPress documents

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, url

My site has both WordPress and non-WordPress files.
The .htaccess file works great with my WordPress files.  For example:
https://suncatcherstudio.com/monograms/index.php
get redirect to:
https://suncatcherstudio.com/monograms/

However, my non-WordPress files, do not get redirect.  For example,
https://suncatcherstudio.com/monogram-maker/index.php
does NOT get redirected.  I want the "index.php" to get removed.
In effect redirecting this document to:
https://suncatcherstudio.com/monogram-maker/

My current .htaccess files looks like this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=301]


# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

One person recommending having two .htaccess files. However, I do not want to have to modify two files every time I add a redirect.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks, Bill

Answer (score 0):

Solved (5 hours later!)  The following code in my PHP programs were causing "index.php" to appear at the end of URLs when the program was called a second time.

```
<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>
```

I simply replaced this code with:

```
   <?php echo htmlspecialchars('https://suncatcherstudio.com/monogram-maker/');?>
```

With PHP_SELF:

```
 First time called: https://suncatcherstudio.com/monogram-maker/
Second time called: https://suncatcherstudio.com/monogram-maker/index.php
```

New approach:

```
  First time called: https://suncatcherstudio.com/monogram-maker/
 Second time called: https://suncatcherstudio.com/monogram-maker/
```